# lvalue required as left operand of assignment <-- I dont get these

Tags: c

why that always appears every time i want to do these:

```
((unsigned char)a.ID[b])=((unsigned int)a.ID[b])/ 10;
```

a.ID its a unsigned char and it contains a group of bits

Comment: You can't assign to the result of a cast.

Comment: Why are you casting `a.ID[b]` when it's already `unsigned char`. You cast the right-hand side to change the type for the calculation, you don't need (and can't, barring terrible pointer aliasing nonsense followed by dereferencing) cast the right hand side to a new type for assignment.

Comment: Tried to change the title to "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" but SO wouldn't let me because there's already a question with that title. Lol.

Answer (score 3):

The target of an assignment has to be an lvalue, i.e. an expression that refers to the location of a variable. But a cast expression returns an rvalue -- a value that isn't associated with a particular storage location in memory. It makes no sense to try to assign to a cast expression, it's not a place you can store into.

You have to do both casts on the right-hand side:

```
a.ID[b] = (unsigned char)(((unsigned int)a.ID[b])/ 10);
```

The inner cast converts the `unsigned char` to `unsigned int` before doing the arithmetic, then the outer cast converts the result back to `unsigned char`.

But there's probably no need for the casts in the first place. `char` is an integer type, so you can perform arithmetic on it just as well as on `int`. The result of dividing the original `unsigned char` by `10` will be the same as when you first cast it to `unsigned int`. You can simply write:

```
a.id[b] /= 10;
```

Comment: If the intent really would be to convert to `unsigned` before the computation (which can make a difference if the type would be signed) the easiest would be to use `10U` instead of `10`.

Comment: But in this case the original type is unsigned, so he's just expanding the size before the computation. It could make a difference if adding or multiplying, but not when dividing.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was just saying because people are much easy in spelling a casts, were using a constant of the correct type would suffice.